# Entering Gibraltar on a multi-entry Schengen?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, gibraltar

I hold a multiple entry Schengen visa and wish to enter Gibraltar. Is this valid without any UK visa, or is a separate category visa required?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 2):

As per the Wikipedia article on [visa policy of British Overseas Territories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_British_Overseas_Territories#Gibraltar),

Specifically considering the fact that you hold a Multi-Entry Schengen Visa, **you don't need a visa if you are a citizen of either China, India, Mongolia, Morocco or Russia**.

> citizens of China, India, Mongolia, Morocco and Russia holding a Schengen multiple entry visa with a minimum remaining validity of 7 days (for a stay of up to 21 days in Gibraltar)

otherwise, make sure you have a multiple entry UK visa,

> holders of a valid UK multiple entry visa issued for 6 months or more or a biometric residence permit (BRP), regardless of category.

Answer (score 1):

Gibraltar does not belong to the Schengen area. It means that you might [need a visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_British_Overseas_Territories#Gibraltar) depending on your citizenship and your situation but also that you should make sure to get Schengen entry and exit stamps if you want to stay sometimes there and don't want to loose time from your 90 days of authorized stay in the Schengen area. That might mean seeking a border guard yourself as I've heard that this border is not always guarded on the Spanish side.